# If statements not correctly printing

Tags: python-3.x

I am not sure as to why but for the if statements it does not correctly print the messages. Whenever I run the program it only runs the else statement but not the rest of the if statements

```
import random
import sys


def main():
    while True:
        aimove = random.randint(1, 3)
        print("|//////////////|")
        print("| 1 - Rock     |")
        print("| 2 - Paper    |")
        print("| 3 - Scissors |")
        print("|//////////////|")
        usermove = input("Choose your move")

        # decides who wins or loses

        if aimove == "1" and usermove == "2":
            print("you won!")
        elif aimove == "1" and usermove == "1":
            print("you tied")
        elif aimove == "1" and usermove == "3":
            print("you lost")
        elif aimove == "2" and usermove == "3":
            print("you won!")
        elif aimove == "2" and usermove == "2":
            print("you tied")
        elif aimove == "2" and usermove == "1":
            print("you lost")
        elif aimove == "3" and usermove == "1":
            print("you won!")
        elif aimove == "3" and usermove == "3":
            print("you tied")
        elif aimove == "3" and usermove == "1":
            print("you lost")
        else:
            sys.exit()

        # Print messages of match

        print("User aimove: " + str(usermove))
        print("Opponent aimove: " + str(aimove))


main()
```

Comment: Remove quotes around “1”. Randint gives an integer, not a string.

Comment: Note that by converting the user's input to `int` to get a common type, you could *dramatically* simplify your tests to test them against each other with `>`, `==` and `<`, rather than exhaustively listing all possibilities. You only need four tests really, one for "usermove` isn't in bounds (in which case you exit), one for `aimove > usermove`, one for `aimove < usermove`, and then the final case where they're equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.randint` gives an integer, not a string. so, if you compare string with int, it'll never be the same.

You can remove quotes around every number like Russ J said in comments, or, you can just convert that into `str()`

```
import random
import sys


def main():
    while True:
        aimove = str(random.randint(1, 3))
        print("|//////////////|")
        print("| 1 - Rock     |")
        print("| 2 - Paper    |")
        print("| 3 - Scissors |")
        print("|//////////////|")
        usermove = input("Choose your move")

        # decides who wins or loses

        if aimove == "1" and usermove == "2":
            print("you won!")
        elif aimove == "1" and usermove == "1":
            print("you tied")
        elif aimove == "1" and usermove == "3":
            print("you lost")
        elif aimove == "2" and usermove == "3":
            print("you won!")
        elif aimove == "2" and usermove == "2":
            print("you tied")
        elif aimove == "2" and usermove == "1":
            print("you lost")
        elif aimove == "3" and usermove == "1":
            print("you won!")
        elif aimove == "3" and usermove == "3":
            print("you tied")
        elif aimove == "3" and usermove == "1":
            print("you lost")
        else:
            sys.exit()

        # Print messages of match

        print("User aimove: " + str(usermove))
        print("Opponent aimove: " + str(aimove))


main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your error:

```
    elif aimove == "3" and usermove == "1":
        print("you won!")
    elif aimove == "3" and usermove == "3":
        print("you tied")
    elif aimove == "3" and usermove == "1":
        print("you lost")
```

3 and 1 combination is for both - won and lost

Also I discovered your error when coding as below:

```
dct = dict()
dct["12"] = "you won!"
dct["11"] = "you tied!"
dct["13"] = "you lost!"
dct["23"] = "you won!"
dct["22"] = "you tied!"
dct["21"] = "you lost!"
dct["31"] = "you won!"
dct["33"] = "you tied!"
dct["32"] = "you lost!"

# OR
#dct = {'12': 'you won!', '11': 'you tied!', '13': 'you lost!', '23': 'you won!', '22': 'you tied!', '21': 'you lost!', '31': 'you won!', '33': 'you tied!', '32': 'you lost!'}

if dct.get(aimove+usermove)
    print(dct[aimove+usermove])
else:
    sys.exit()
```

So replace your corresponding code and get rid of all elifs